# Error 488 Not acceptable here

Tags: ssl, asterisk, sip, rtp

Hello I know there are already lot of topics about this error (or perhaps I don't have the same problem) but none of them answered my question, I am in a local network with blink on my PC and my asterisk server is on an external server hosted by ovh (so there is nat to do). I control the server via encrypted ssh session ofc.
As long as the call is not encrypted, everything is fine, I can call any user I want. But when I started to encrypt my traffic everything went wrong and I can't find why.I've generated certficate for both client and server, the traffic is encrypted because I can't see anything in wireshark(I can't see encrypted traffic but I see non-encrypted traffic). Blink is configured correctly with SDES mandatory, .pem file, car.crt , proxy on port 5061 tls, but I think the error is somewhere else.
Myconig for sip.conf is like this:

```
[general]
udpbindaddr=0.0.0.0
tcpenable=yes                    ; Enable server for incoming TCP connections (default is no)
tcpbindaddr=0.0.0.0             ; IP address for TCP server to bind to (0.0.0.0 binds to all interfaces)                                ; Optionally add a port number, 192.168.1.1:5062 (default is port 5060)
tlsenable=yes               ; Enable server for incoming TLS (secure) connections (default is no)
tlsbindaddr=0.0.0.0   
transport=udp
disallow=all       
allow=ulaw                     ; Allow codecs in order of preference
allow=alaw
dtmfmode = rfc2833
tlscertfile=/etc/asterisk/keys/asterisk.pem
tlscafile=/etc/asterisk/keys/ca.crt
tlscipher=ALL
tlsclientmethod=tlsv1 
[201](can't communicate instant 488 error)
type=friend
username=vincent
context=from-sip
host=dynamic
secret=not4usry
callerid=vincent<201>
mailbox=201@default
nat=comedia
transport=tls
encryption=yes
[203](no tls user and can communicate with the ones who don't use tls)
type=friend
username=antoine
context=from-sip
host=dynamic
secret=not4usry
callerid=antoine<203>
mailbox=203@default
nat=comedia
```

Certificates have been generated using ./ast_tls_cert....

RTP logs

> == Using SIP RTP CoS mark 5 [May 11 15:34:33]
>   WARNING[21893][C-00000d0e]: chan_sip.c:10803 process_sdp: Rejecting
>   secure audio stream without encryption details: audio 50026 RTP/SAVP
>   113 9 0 8 101

SIP LOGS

> INVITE sip:203@vps466556.ovh.net SIP/2.0
>
> Via: SIP/2.0/TLS
>   192.168.1.35:53076;rport;branch=z9hG4bKPj275105fe6a304b89b2b18ee5186b5085;alias
>
> Max-Forwards: 70
>
> From: "Vincent"
>   ;tag=523fe49e3a8646608481fbac0801b605
>
> To:
>
> Contact:
>
> Call-ID: 0fb841de523e4ff0a74514247bb3445a
>
> CSeq: 4966 INVITE
>
> Allow: SUBSCRIBE, NOTIFY, INVITE, ACK, BYE, CANCEL, UPDATE, MESSAGE,
>   REFER
>
> Supported: replaces, norefersub, gruu
>
> User-Agent: Blink 3.0.0 (Windows)
>
> Content-Type: application/sdp
>
> Content-Length:   425
>
> v=0
>
> o=- 3735043210 3735043210 IN IP4 192.168.1.35
>
> s=Blink 3.0.0 (Windows)
>
> t=0 0
>
> m=audio 50004 RTP/AVP 113 9 0 8 101
>
> c=IN IP4 192.168.1.35
>
> a=rtcp:50005
>
> a=rtpmap:113 opus/48000/2
>
> a=fmtp:113 useinbandfec=1
>
> a=rtpmap:9 G722/8000
>
> a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000
>
> a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000
>
> a=rtpmap:101 telephone-event/8000
>
> a=fmtp:101 0-16
>
> a=zrtp-hash:1.10
>   af10bf32a78e03147ffbf2859f96cc8d401048ee46a1f2cb961c20139b219913
>
> a=sendrecv
>
> -- 2018-05-11 16:00:11.003276 [blink.exe 3320]: RECEIVED: Packet 136, +0:06:21.266013
>   54.37.8.124:5061 -(SIP over TLS)-> 192.168.1.35:53076 SIP/2.0 401 Unauthorized
>
> Via: SIP/2.0/TLS
>   192.168.1.35:53076;branch=z9hG4bKPj275105fe6a304b89b2b18ee5186b5085;alias;received=90.112.223.194;rport=53076
>
> From: "Vincent"
>   ;tag=523fe49e3a8646608481fbac0801b605
>
> To: ;tag=as50eb1885
>
> Call-ID: 0fb841de523e4ff0a74514247bb3445a
>
> CSeq: 4966 INVITE
>
> Server: Asterisk PBX 13.21.0
>
> Allow: INVITE, ACK, CANCEL, OPTIONS, BYE, REFER, SUBSCRIBE, NOTIFY,
>   INFO, PUBLISH, MESSAGE
>
> Supported: replaces, timer
>
> -Authenticate: Digest algorithm=MD5, realm="asterisk", nonce="6650a402"
>
> Content-Length: 0
>
> -- 2018-05-11 16:00:11.004276 [blink.exe 3320]: SENDING: Packet 137, +0:06:21.267013
>   192.168.1.35:53076 -(SIP over TLS)-> 54.37.8.124:5061 ACK sip:203@vps466556.ovh.net SIP/2.0
>
> Via: SIP/2.0/TLS
>   192.168.1.35:53076;rport;branch=z9hG4bKPj275105fe6a304b89b2b18ee5186b5085;alias
>
> Max-Forwards: 70
>
> From: "Vincent"
>   ;tag=523fe49e3a8646608481fbac0801b605
>
> To: ;tag=as50eb1885
>
> Call-ID: 0fb841de523e4ff0a74514247bb3445a
>
> CSeq: 4966 ACK
>
> User-Agent: Blink 3.0.0 (Windows)
>
> Content-Length:  0
>
> -- 2018-05-11 16:00:11.005276 [blink.exe 3320]: SENDING: Packet 138, +0:06:21.268013
>   192.168.1.35:53076 -(SIP over TLS)-> 54.37.8.124:5061 INVITE sip:203@vps466556.ovh.net SIP/2.0
>
> Via: SIP/2.0/TLS
>   192.168.1.35:53076;rport;branch=z9hG4bKPj3e8da342afaa41a385d9989648fd069f;alias
>
> Max-Forwards: 70
>
> From: "Vincent"
>   ;tag=523fe49e3a8646608481fbac0801b605
>
> To:
>
> Contact:
>
> Call-ID: 0fb841de523e4ff0a74514247bb3445a
>
> CSeq: 4967 INVITE
>
> Allow: SUBSCRIBE, NOTIFY, INVITE, ACK, BYE, CANCEL, UPDATE, MESSAGE,
>   REFER
>
> Supported: replaces, norefersub, gruu
>
> User-Agent: Blink 3.0.0 (Windows)
>
> Authorization: Digest username="201", realm="asterisk",
>   nonce="6650a402", uri="sip:203@vps466556.ovh.net",
>   response="dcd6fcd9d8b7381f86f07e1326aa9134", algorithm=MD5
>
> Content-Type: application/sdp
>
> Content-Length:   425
>
> v=0
>
> o=- 3735043210 3735043210 IN IP4 192.168.1.35
>
> s=Blink 3.0.0 (Windows)
>
> t=0 0
>
> m=audio 50004 RTP/AVP 113 9 0 8 101
>
> c=IN IP4 192.168.1.35
>
> a=rtcp:50005
>
> a=rtpmap:113 opus/48000/2
>
> a=fmtp:113 useinbandfec=1
>
> a=rtpmap:9 G722/8000
>
> a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000
>
> a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000
>
> a=rtpmap:101 telephone-event/8000
>
> a=fmtp:101 0-16
>
> a=zrtp-hash:1.10
>   af10bf32a78e03147ffbf2859f96cc8d401048ee46a1f2cb961c20139b219913
>
> a=sendrecv
>
> -- 2018-05-11 16:00:11.087226 [blink.exe 3320]: RECEIVED: Packet 139, +0:06:21.349963
>   54.37.8.124:5061 -(SIP over TLS)-> 192.168.1.35:53076 SIP/2.0 488 Not acceptable here
>
> Via: SIP/2.0/TLS
>   192.168.1.35:53076;branch=z9hG4bKPj3e8da342afaa41a385d9989648fd069f;alias;received=90.112.223.194;rport=53076
>
> From: "Vincent"
>   ;tag=523fe49e3a8646608481fbac0801b605
>
> To: ;tag=as50eb1885
>
> Call-ID: 0fb841de523e4ff0a74514247bb3445a
>
> CSeq: 4967 INVITE
>
> Server: Asterisk PBX 13.21.0
>
> Allow: INVITE, ACK, CANCEL, OPTIONS, BYE, REFER, SUBSCRIBE, NOTIFY,
>   INFO, PUBLISH, MESSAGE
>
> Supported: replaces, timer
>
> Content-Length: 0
>
> -- 2018-05-11 16:00:11.088227 [blink.exe 3320]: SENDING: Packet 140, +0:06:21.350964
>   192.168.1.35:53076 -(SIP over TLS)-> 54.37.8.124:5061 ACK sip:203@vps466556.ovh.net SIP/2.0
>
> Via: SIP/2.0/TLS
>   192.168.1.35:53076;rport;branch=z9hG4bKPj3e8da342afaa41a385d9989648fd069f;alias
>
> Max-Forwards: 70
>
> From: "Vincent"
>   ;tag=523fe49e3a8646608481fbac0801b605
>
> To: ;tag=as50eb1885
>
> Call-ID: 0fb841de523e4ff0a74514247bb3445a
>
> CSeq: 4967 ACK
>
> User-Agent: Blink 3.0.0 (Windows)
>
> Content-Length:  0

Thanks for your help,  Vince

Comment: This might help: https://serverfault.com/questions/731932/asterisk-with-softphone-and-webphone

Comment: 488 usualy mean no acceptable codec. Sorry, not gooing read 10 pages of text.

Comment: Looks like you're using zrtp.  Does your Asterisk server support it?

Answer (score 1):

Your SIP endpoint specifies encryption=yes, but the INVITE from your client specifies RTP/AVP, not RTP/SAVP.  iirc, Blink has an option for optimistic or mandatory encryption; you'll need to change it to mandatory.

Comment: It worked ty ♥, but also REINSTALLED the SRTP library.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the same problem as me, reinstall the Srtp library and asterisk, also log sip request because I had a bug where Blink didn't send register request anymore (even when pushing that register button 1000times) so I downloaded PhonerLite and everything worked perfectly